# Pan and 2 Finger Pinch simultaneous iOS -at the same time-

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, pinch, pan, simultaneous

2 Gesture recognizer:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *twoFingerPinch = 
[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
[croppper addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerPinch];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *PanRecognizer = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)] autorelease];
[croppper addGestureRecognizer:PanRecognizer];
```

and:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {        
    return YES;
}
```

But pinch and pan at the same time is not working...
often i can pinch because the pan recognizer is on.

regards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're setting the delegate for each gesture recognizer. `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` is a delegate method, and so if the gesture recognizer has no delegate, this method won't be invoked.

As a result, the default return value will be `NO`, and so the gestures won't be recognised simultaneously.

Comment: +1 for correct answer. In other words, add the following two lines to your code: `twoFingerPinch.delegate = self;` and `PanRecognizer.delegate = self;`. Also consider renaming the second gestureRecognizer to use a lowercase initial.

Comment: your right! thank you!     (twoFingerPinch.delegate = self;)
i

Comment: Stupid web cache - now my answer looks ridiculous :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting yourself as the recognisers delegate?

```
[twoFingerPinch setDelgate:self];
...
[PanRecognizer setDelegate:self];
```

PS I'd also try to get a more consistent naming scheme for your variables!